# Swift :Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring')

Tags: swift

I'm working on a little project and I came across this error which I can't find on the Internet.

This is my code:

```
let bufferRecieved = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: length, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: true)
guard let delimiterFirstIndex = bufferRecieved?.index(of: ":")!,
    let name = bufferRecieved![..<delimiterFirstIndex],
    let message = bufferRecieved![delimiterFirstIndex...] else {
    return nil
}
```

I get:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') for the two instructions

```
let name = bufferRecieved![..<delimiterFirstIndex],
let message = bufferRecieved![delimiterFirstIndex...]
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just as a note, there is a specific method to use for dividing a `String` like this called [`split`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894564-split). It's a little safer and more self-documenting than using an index. Example: `let split = bufferRecieved.split(separator: ":", maxSplits: 1); guard split.count == 2 else { return nil };  let name = String(split[0]); let message = String(split[1])`

Comment: The whole point `guard` is to safe check and unwrap optionals. Using all of the bad `!` operators with a `guard` is a terrible practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` and `message` aren't Optionals, so there's no need for them to be part of the conditional binding. Just put them after the guard statement:

```
guard let bufferRecieved = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: length, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: true),
    let delimiterFirstIndex = bufferRecieved.index(of: ":") else {
    return nil
}

let name = bufferRecieved[..<delimiterFirstIndex]
let message = bufferRecieved[delimiterFirstIndex...]
use(name, message)
```